# How to trigger prefers-color-scheme in :root and for global variable?

Tags: html, css, color-scheme

I have written css code similar to this:

```
:root {
  ...some global color related variables
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    ...global colors are overwritten
  } 
}
```

and I have a button that toggles between dark mode and light mode which its javascript code works like this:

```
document.documentElement.style = `color-scheme: ${mode};`; // mode is either light or dark
const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name="color-scheme"]');
meta.content = mode; // mode is either light or dark
```

And it applies its style which is `color-scheme: light or dark` to the `html` element and all of the other elements as well, but it doesn't trigger the `prefers-color-scheme` in the styles related to the `:root` and global variables or even some other places. How can I be able to do this?

---

PS1: When I change the color scheme of the website using chrome browser itself (using `Emulate CSS prefers-color-scheme: dark` in dev tools) it works just fine and the global variables get overwritten.

PS2: I'm trying to implement dark mode using color schemes and avoid having to add a class or anything like that and It's because of some default styling of the browsers that gets applied thinking it's a light moded website which isn't (like -internal-light-dark color in auto-filling an input)

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution you're looking for is adding the media query **after the root** like this:

```css
:root {
  ...some global color related variables
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    color-scheme: dark;
    /* variable overrides ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: the code was written in scss, but I'll change it to CSS to avoid confusion